# Set mapleader to CTRL in VIM

Tags: vim

I'm trying to set mapleader to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, but it's not working.

I tried this:

```
let mapleader="\<cr>"
```

Is there a reason why this won't work? Is it even possible to set the mapleader to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key?

EDIT: Actually, I'm using GVim, not VIM.

Comment: FYI, `<CR>` is `Return/Enter`, not `Ctrl`

Comment: Indeed, that was a typo

Answer (score 4):

You cannot map to *modifier keys* (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>) alone; they can only be used **in combination with other keys** that represent printable characters (like `<C-a>` = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>). That's mostly due to the fact that terminals do not send keypress events for modifier keys alone. There are unfortunately even limitations in those combinations (also in GVIM). Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished.

Answer (score 1):

Leader is a special key in Vim. It cannot be combined with modfiers such as C-something.

You can however do somethign like

```
nnoremap <c-\> :MyFunction<cr>
```

Btw, `<cr>` is enter, return, ...